# Interpolating data from Excel

Tags: import, interpolation, excel

Sorry for the probably mainstream question, but I have not found the answer I was looking for yet.

I have this Excel file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UhkYdoaqXQIsf6opOx-EBgG7xPxxHga3/view and I want to import the two-column data therein, define a function $g(t)$ from their interpolation and plot it.

I have tried simple code lines as

```
mydata = Import["gstar.xlsx"]
g = Interpolation[mydata]
```

but it gives me the error message `Interpolation::inder: The order-2 derivative of {0.000101685,4.13102} is not a tensor of rank 2 with dimensions 2.`

I have also tried with `g = ListInterpolation[mydata]`, but I get `ListInterpolation::inhr: Requested order is too high; order has been reduced to {0,3,1}.`

I don't understand what are the problems. In fact, if I try to plot the list of data with `ListLogLogPlot[mydata]` I am able to visualize the data and it seems that the import process was actually successful.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Remove the chart from input excel file; or try `mydata2 = Import["gstar.xlsx", {"Data", 1,  All, ;; 2}]; Interpolation[mydata2]`?

Comment: Sorry for the chart, but it doesn't affect the problem. However, it seems that your second method works, thank you! May you explain the syntax `{"Data", 1, All, ;; 2}` to me?

Comment: Lele, posted the comment as answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
mydata2 = Import["gstar.xlsx", {"Data", 1, All, ;; 2}]; 
Interpolation[mydata2]
```

`{"Data", sheetlist, rowlist, columnlist}` specification extracts data from sheets in `sheetlist` the rows in `rowlist` and columns in `columnlist`. So  `{"Data", 1, All, ;; 2}` says "get the array of data in columns 1 and 2 form all rows of sheet 1".

See [`XLSX >> Import Elements`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/format/XLSX.html) for further examples.